# ArcGIS Pro Pixel Editor - Saving takes forever

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, editing, save

I have to reclass many small parts in a classified land use raster using pixel editor. However, when I click "save" after a few edits, the saving process takes forever (hours until I force quit ArcGIS Pro). I now save after every single edit, saving takes about 20-40 sec. But waiting those seconds every time really sums up to a big amount of time.

My raster file is placed in a geodatabase. I tried to edit the raster outside the gdb and saved it as .tif, but the same problem here.

Are there any recommendations for e.g. raster format and size? (mine is 3 GB)

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 3GB raster is a large dataset so any edits will take time. Perhaps you can get smarter with your edits. You don't actually describe in any way what you are doing so maybe these pixel locations you are updating are coming from another source of data such as a point dataset. In that case you could convert that into a raster and add/subtract/replace using standard geoprocessing tools.

Comment: @annec, you can also narrow it down if it's with the app or data by creating a subset and test.

Comment: @hornybydd: Thanks for your answer. I'm using the "Replace Value" function to correct small misclassified areas.

Comment: @YogeshChavan: That means, splitting the file into smaller rasters? I'm gonna try that, thank you

Comment: Yep, I have split the raster to tiles of around 200mb, now it works well!